# Configure run command in Awesome window manager

Tags: awesome

I am using the Awesome window manager - I like it.

When I press mod+R I get the run command on the top left of the screen. Here if I type in a command exactly correct it runs the application.

How can I make the mod+R box smart? Example: If I press 'f' and then 'up arrow' it will auto search for applications (or through my run history) that begin with 'f' (like firefox).

Comment: @user35186 Consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the standard awesome prompt just doesn't provide this function, you'd have to switch to a different one, I'm using http://code.google.com/p/bashrun2 which behaves very much like standard bash, it won't do the firefoxy thing though (unless you use things like !f[ENTER]). After installing bashrun you need to edit /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua to change mod+r default behaviour, find the lines:

```
-- Prompt
awful.key({ modkey },            "r",     function () mypromptbox[mouse.screen]:run() end),
```

and by applying information from http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_use_a_keycode_in_a_keybinding.3F we arrive at something like

```
-- Prompt
awful.key({ modkey },            "r",     function () exec("bashrun2") end),
```

This seemes fine to me, but I havent tested this lua code myself.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
I (the original poster) had to do:

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "r",         function () awful.util.spawn('bashrun2') end)
```

Answer (score 8):

update to awesome 3.5, and use mod+p